# I'm missing 15k from my chat reputation - possibly related to a prior suspension?

Tags: support, reputation, ban

I got a 7-day ban in April from Web Applications, and my rep count on my  [Chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/44764/franck-dernoncourt) I see that my rep from WebApps, which temporarily went down to 1 during the ban, hasn't come back.

My chat profile says that I have 340k network-wide but my flair says I have 355k, which is a difference of 15k, about what I have on Web Applications (~13.4k).

Comment: I see you at 340K. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @rene just trying to help debug, indeed doesn't matter personally.

Comment: Links to random pages don't really help. Going to the generic "all" page requires someone to take the time to find your specific profile - why not just link to your chat profile rather than linking to the all chat users page?

Comment: @Catija good point, thanks sorry I didn't mean to specifically point to myself, just mentioning some issue in the chat pages.

Comment: Chat data only refreshes if you actually _use_ chat. If you never visit, the data becomes stale. It is possible chat just hasn't attempted to do a refresh since you were unsuspended. Have you tried visiting chat while logged in (it says you haven't visited in 30 days)?

Comment: @animuson thanks, no. I wasn't aware of that, sounds like an answer.

Comment: If that does fix it, might be worth retagging this to support and then the answer will fit.

Comment: @Catija thx, will keep you posted

Comment: If you want to try posting a chat message to see if that results in chat updating your profile, you could just post in the [Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox). If that doesn't work, you could try temporarily changing your parent user (in your chat profile) to Web Applications to see if that causes it to update. Other than that, any moderator can try updating your chat profile from your parent site, perhaps with a temporary change to Web Applications as your parent site.

Comment: Franck, You are OK on [SO Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/395857/franck-dernoncourt), but are [missing ~ > 6,994 on MSE Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/178179/franck-dernoncourt) too.

Comment: @Rob thanks, yes 4h ago I sent a message to the SO sandbox chat, then 2h ago I sent a message to the SO sandbox chat. Weird that chat data only refreshes if one actually use chat if you ask me.

Comment: Yes it is strange, but you used MSE chat 35 days ago, and [apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366255/im-missing-15k-from-my-chat-reputation-possibly-related-to-a-prior-suspension#comment1220242_366255) used SO chat 30 days ago - did you really [gain 7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178179/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation) - 15 thousand reputation in a month (having been here 9 years); your Reputation Graph says "no".

Comment: @Rob got it, strange indeed :-/ I've never been much active on MSE.

Comment: It's an extreme form of caching. Always caching.

Comment: A 15k difference more accurately reflects your reputation on Area 51 of 15,060, which is a much more likely site for something to be wonky wrt. the rest of the network.

Comment: @animuson I've sent a message in the SO sandbox as well in the meta SE sandbox >7 days ago. The issue is still present.

Comment: 2022. The issue is still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue got fixed today. I don't know what fixed it. [Snapshot of my chat profile on  2022-01-22](https://web.archive.org/web/20220122112421/https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/44764/franck-dernoncourt).

Comment: I can close this question of mine: [Mysteriously getting signed out of my accounts (never happened even in a week of inactivity)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372269/mysteriously-getting-signed-out-of-my-accounts-never-happened-even-in-a-week-of) and link your answer, as *This question already has answers here*, because that thing was also fixed and *I don't know what fixed it*.

Comment: They might be entirely different mysterious fixes. Chat has a lot of wierd things including caching that sometimes needs a kick. The log in system ... well occationally does wierd things too.